# More Windows 10 Bluetooth Audio Problems

Tags: windows, speakers

I've been trying to get my Dell XPS 13 (Windows 10 Pro, version 10.0.18363, build 18363) to communicate with a JBL Flip 4, or some very expensive Bose Quiet Comfort 35 II's for about nine months off and and on, but although the problem seems very common I still can't make them work, and most of the answers I can find elsewhere are pretty much "update the drivers" and that's it.
Today I found this site, and then the following question, and thought I'd discovered the Holy Grail of answers :-
**Windows 10 computer paired w/ bluetooth speaker, but doesn't send music to speaker
Ask Question Asked 4 years, 2 months ago Active 11 months ago Viewed 242k times**

**Response 6 was very promising**, thank you whoever wrote it, everything worked all the way down to where it said:

**This time you should see two entries: "Bluetooth AV" and "Bluetooth Stereo", choose "Bluetooth Stereo", click Next and click Yes if asked anything** -

But I only get Bluetooth AV, **NO Bluetooth Stereo !**

I also tried going back to the beginning and trying the "Headset Audio Gateway Service" option, but that also failed.
I'm presuming something in Windows has been changed since this response was given. Just to be incredibly annoying both the JBL speaker and Bose headphones work with my iPhone and a recently purchased Samsung Tablet, so I've presumed it must be a windows issue.

Can anybody help and tell me the best course of action please?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Bluetooth simply isn't handled very well by Windows unless you are on a desktop computer and your system doesn't have to deal with lid/dock events changing aspects of multiple audio devices.  Most of these experiences were on older Dell hardware.

Some things you can try:

- Bypass the Bluetooth hardware in the laptop: try getting a Bluetooth USB adapter and see if you have better luck with that.
- Bring up the Run dialog, type `mmsys.cpl` and press Enter, and disable every audio device but your Bluetooth devices.
- If you only care about hearing the audio and not using any mic as a headset: Bypass the Windows Bluetooth stack entirely and look for a device that accepts headphone jack inputs and converts to Bluetooth (search for "aux to Bluetooth adapter" for examples).